Using Postgres 16 with Spring Boot 3.3.0
I just upgraded from spring-boot 3.2.3 -> 3.3.0. After the upgrade flyway refuses to connect to postgres:
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: PostgreSQL 16.2
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseTypeRegister.getDatabaseTypeForConnection(DatabaseTypeRegister.java:105)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:73)
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:134)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:147)

What is the expected way to connect to postgres 16 using spring-boot 3.3.0 and flyway?

There is pinned issue to announce about extracting database support out from flyway-core.
Try to add this dependency to your project:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>


in your pom.xml add this :
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>10.15.2</version>
</dependency>

add also in your application.yml this :
spring:
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    baseline-on-migrate: true


Will it work with Postgres 16.x ? I'm still getting org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: PostgreSQL 16.3
